# How to Eliminate Duplicate Values using MS ACCESS QUERY

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

```
SELECT [Household Info].[Household Head], [Household Info].Gender, [Household Info].[Household Members], Count(IIf([Household Members.Gender]="Male",0)) AS [Total Male], Count(IIf([Household Members.Gender]="Female",0)) AS [Total Female], Count(IIf([Household Members.Gender]="M","Male","Female")) AS [Total Gender], [Household Data].[Area of Homelot (ha)], [Household Data].[Area of Farmlot (ha)], [Household Data].[Area of Homelot (ha)]+[Area of Farmlot (ha)] AS [Total Area Occupied], [Household Data].[Date of Occupancy] 
FROM [Household Data], [Household Info] INNER JOIN 
[Household Members] ON [Household Info].HID = [Household Members].HID 
GROUP BY [Household Info].[Household Head], [Household Info].Gender, [Household Info].[Household Members], [Household Data].[Area of Homelot (ha)], [Household Data].[Area of Farmlot (ha)], [Household Data].[Area of Homelot (ha)]+[Area of Farmlot (ha)], [Household Data].[Date of Occupancy];
```

This is the output of my query in MS ACCESS

output
  [image]

I want to eliminate the two duplicate values, because that's supposed to be just only 1 Grace Poe, 1 PPeter Caapegsan and 1 Rodrigo Duterte.

So yeah that's supposed to show only 3 data, but I don't know why it duplicates.

Comment: have you tried "Using an Append Query"

Comment: @DDave Yes, I even tried the "Find Duplicates Query Wizard". It still won't work on that query.. But when I try a separate just only "Household Head" it does work, but in this one that contains many data it won't.

Answer (score 0):

try to use a Primary Key. like putting it (for example) to column reference_numb (ex 1 gracepoe 2 Ppeter Caapegsan 3 Rodrigo duterte) your reference_numb is the number(based on my ex.) and primary key. the name maybe your column full_Name so that you can't insert data with the same reference number